# Tomcat JSF Error

Tags: jsf, tomcat

I'm building a page in JSF and am running it on Tomcat in Eclipse. Everything was working quite well until I started getting these errors everytime I try to load the page. The page looks wrong and the eclipse console shows me around 12 of errors like this one:

```
Dec 19, 2013 9:23:26 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /img/sep.jsp.  
To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

The funny thing is that the file in this particular error isnt sep.jsp but sep.PNG...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- index.xhtml -->
<!-- JSF page that displays the current time on the web server -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
  <title>WebTime: A Simple Example</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h1>Current time on the web server: #{webTimeBean.time}</h1>
  <img src="img/sep.png" alt="sep.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;
float:right;" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the source code of your page

Comment: Here it is, I removed everyhting that's not important, I get the error for every picture I put in the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its recommended to use only jsf TAGS and not mixing standard html and jsf.

a valid xhtml for jsf use should be somthing like this:

you don't need to declare xml at the top of your page!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Test</title>    
</h:head>
<body>
<f:view> 
<h:outputText value="hello"></h:outputText>
<h:graphicImage name="img/sep.png" class="LOGO" alt="Image not found!"></h:graphicImage>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

in your web.xml, check the Faces Servlet Pattern. it seems to me that tomcat tries to compile every file under / as jsf. so change your faces pathern and

try it and let me know if you still have the same "warning".

Comment: The problem was in my web.xml file... Under url-pattern I had only "/". I changed it to /MyApplication/* and now it works great. 
Thank for the tip :)